# Why can't I use IIFE to generate an object value with this context?

Tags: javascript, object, this, iife

I have this function

```
const obj = {
  key1: 0.1,
  key2: (function(){return this.key1 +' units'})(),
  key3: function(){return this.key1 +' units'},
}
```

ob is actually `{ key1: 0.1, key2: 'undefined units', Function }`

and obj.key3() gives  `0.1 units` as expected

Comment: because `this` isn't `obj`

Comment: `this` refers to the enclosing function's context in your code, and not to the `obj`.

Comment: `obj.key3()` will run the function after the object creation, and it runs as a method call, assigning `this`. `obj.key2` will run the function where `obj` is declared but not yet assigned, and IIFE does not assign `this`.

Comment: makes sense, how can I access the global `obj` from the IIFE?

Comment: you can't because if you try you'll get `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'obj' before initialization`

Comment: if you must have something like this, then I guess ... `const obj = {
  key1: 0.1,
  key3: function(){return this.key1 +' units'}
};
obj.key2 = (function(){return obj.key1 +' units'})();` will give you the functionality you want

Answer (score 0):

IIFE gets called while the `obj` get initialized. `key1` is inside the `obj`. So you get an undefined error. Declare `key1` early.

```js
var obj = (function(){
  var key1 = 0.1;
  
  return {
    key1: key1,
    key2: (function(){
      return key1 +' units';
    })(),
    key3: function(){
      return this.key1 +' units'
    }
  };
})();

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: In this case why do you need the internal IIFE at all? Why not just `key2: key1 +' units',`?

Comment: I just added it since it was in the original code and his question was about the iife. We can do like `key2: key1 +' units'` as well.

Comment: *"IIFE gets called before the obj get initialized*"... how? It's the very object initialisation that defines the IIFE at the first place. The way you worded it seems like a precognition! Maybe *during initialisation*, *before finishing* or something like that are better choices...

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado